# Snake turtle don't grow up

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm beginner and I can't undertstand why my code doesn't work. I make snake game. My snake must grow but it doesn't. You can run the code in python interpreter and see how it works. And when I run a code, head of snake moves slower and slower. It isn't really good. I would be thankful for help. Python version is 3.10(probably it is also important)

```
import turtle
import random
import time

segments = []
delay = 0.1
score = 0
highest = 0
x = 0
y = 0

cl2 = random.choice(['orange', 'purple', 'blue'])
cl = random.choice(['yellow', 'blue', 'green'])
sh = random.choice(['square', 'triangle', 'circle'])

foodx = random.randrange(-245, 245)
foody = random.randrange(-245, 245)

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title('Snake_game')
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.setup(width=600)
wn.tracer(0)

head = turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(0)
head.color(cl)
head.fillcolor(cl2)
head.shape('square')
head.shapesize(0.80, 0.80)
head.penup()
head.direction = 'stop'
head.goto(x, y)

food = turtle.Turtle()
food.speed(0)
food.shape(sh)
food.shapesize(0.65, 0.65)
food.color('red')
food.fillcolor('orange')
food.penup()
food.goto(foodx, foody)

score_b = turtle.Turtle()
score_b.speed(0)
score_b.shape('square')
score_b.color('white')
score_b.hideturtle()
score_b.penup()
score_b.goto(0, 250)
score_b.write('Score : 0, the_highest_score : 0', align='center', font=('Arial', 19, 'italic'))

def go_up():
    if head.direction != 'down':
        head.direction = 'up'
def go_down():
    if head.direction != 'up':
        head.direction = 'down'
def go_left():
    if head.direction != 'right':
        head.direction = 'left'
def go_right():
    if head.direction != 'left':
        head.direction = 'right'

speed = 0.1

def move():
    if head.direction == 'up':
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y+speed)
    if head.direction == 'down':
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y-speed)
    if head.direction == 'left':
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x-speed)
    if head.direction == 'right':
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x+speed)

wn.listen()
wn.onkey(go_up, 'w')
wn.onkey(go_left, 'a')
wn.onkey(go_down, 's')
wn.onkey(go_right, 'd')

while True:
    wn.update()
    move()
    if head.xcor() > 300 or head.xcor() < -300 or head.ycor() > 310 or head.ycor() < -310:
        time.sleep = 1
        head.goto(0, 0)
        head.direction = 'stop'
        cl2 = random.choice(['orange', 'purple', 'blue'])
        cl = random.choice(['yellow', 'blue', 'green'])
        sh = random.choice(['square', 'triangle', 'circle'])
        for segment in segments:
            segment.goto(1000, 1000)
        segment.clear()
    if head.distance(food) < 10:
        x = random.randint(-290, 290)
        y = random.randint(-290, 290)
        food.goto(x, y)

        segment = turtle.Turtle()
        segment.speed(0)
        segment.shape('square')
        segment.shapesize(0.80, 0.80)
        segment.color(cl)
        segment.fillcolor(cl2)
        segment.penup()
        segments.append(segment)

        for i in range(len(segments)-1, 0, -1):
            x = segments[i-1].xcor()
            y = segments[i-1].ycor()
            segment.goto(x, y)

        if len(segments) > 0:
            x = head.xcor()
            y = head.ycor()
            segments[0].goto(x, y)
        move()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: `time.sleep = 1` should be `time.sleep(1)` and `head.direction = 'stop'` won't work as you think. `while True` with `sleep` isn't a very good timer--`Screen().ontimer` is a bit better. Your turtle grows but you need to move the tail.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre]. We cannot fix multiple problems in an entire program; we can *answer* a question - *one, specific* question at a time - which is the question that remains *after* your [best attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to figure it out yourself first, *isolate* the part of the code that causes the problem, and show us *minimal* code that reproduces the error (we should be able to copy and paste to see the *exact* problem, *directly*).

Comment: Please also keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. We are not interested in your level of experience, [or your gratitude](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it). We are interested in *the code, and the related question*.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many problems.

You have wrong indentations. You move segments inside `if head.distance(food) < 10:` - so it moves it only once. You should do it in every loop.

You move segments after moving head - so segment has the same position as head. You should move segments before you get new position for head.

The biggest problem is that your snake moves smoothly using `speed = 0.1` so when you create new segment then it may get position `head + 0.1` and it displays one segment on another segment and you can't see segments. It would have to get position `head + head_size`. Maybe first try classic version where snake moves from square to square using `speed = head_size`

Another problem: in `for`-loop you get value from `segments[i-1]` and you set `segment.goto(x, y)` but it should be `segments[i].goto(x, y)`

---

Working example with classic snake which moves from square to square.

```
import turtle
import random
import time

segments = []
delay = 0.1
score = 0
highest = 0
x = 0
y = 0

cl2 = random.choice(['orange', 'purple', 'blue'])
cl  = random.choice(['yellow', 'blue', 'green'])
sh  = random.choice(['square', 'triangle', 'circle'])

foodx = random.randrange(-245, 245)
foody = random.randrange(-245, 245)

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title('Snake_game')
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.setup(width=600)
wn.tracer(0)

head = turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(0)
head.color(cl)
head.fillcolor(cl2)
head.shape('square')
head.shapesize(0.80, 0.80)
head.penup()
head.direction = 'stop'
head.goto(x, y)

food = turtle.Turtle()
food.speed(0)
food.shape(sh)
food.shapesize(0.65, 0.65)
food.color('red')
food.fillcolor('orange')
food.penup()
food.goto(foodx, foody)

score_b = turtle.Turtle()
score_b.speed(0)
score_b.shape('square')
score_b.color('white')
score_b.hideturtle()
score_b.penup()
score_b.goto(0, 250)
score_b.write('Score : 0, the_highest_score : 0', align='center', font=('Arial', 19, 'italic'))

def go_up():
    if head.direction != 'down':
        head.direction = 'up'
def go_down():
    if head.direction != 'up':
        head.direction = 'down'
def go_left():
    if head.direction != 'right':
        head.direction = 'left'
def go_right():
    if head.direction != 'left':
        head.direction = 'right'

def move():
    if head.direction == 'up':
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y+speed)
    if head.direction == 'down':
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y-speed)
    if head.direction == 'left':
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x-speed)
    if head.direction == 'right':
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x+speed)

wn.listen()
wn.onkey(go_up, 'w')
wn.onkey(go_left, 'a')
wn.onkey(go_down, 's')
wn.onkey(go_right, 'd')

# --- all changes are only below ---

speed = 20

while True:
    
    if head.direction != 'stop':
        
        if head.xcor() > 300 or head.xcor() < -300 or head.ycor() > 310 or head.ycor() < -310:
            time.sleep(1)
            head.goto(0, 0)
            head.direction = 'stop'
            cl2 = random.choice(['orange', 'purple', 'blue'])
            cl  = random.choice(['yellow', 'blue', 'green'])
            sh  = random.choice(['square', 'triangle', 'circle'])
            segments = []  # remove all segments

        # first add new segment

        if head.distance(food) < 10:
            x = random.randint(-290, 290)
            y = random.randint(-290, 290)
            food.goto(x, y)

            segment = turtle.Turtle()
            segment.speed(0)
            segment.shape('square')
            segment.shapesize(0.80, 0.80)
            segment.color(cl)
            segment.fillcolor(cl2)
            segment.penup()
            segments.append(segment)

        # next move segments
        
        for i in range(len(segments)-1, 0, -1):
            print('move')
            x = segments[i-1].xcor()
            y = segments[i-1].ycor()
            segments[i].goto(x, y)

        if len(segments) > 0:
            print('move')
            x = head.xcor()
            y = head.ycor()
            segments[0].goto(x, y)
        
        # next move head
        
        move()

    # --- in every loop ---

    # finally display all in new positions
        
    wn.update()

    time.sleep(.2)  # reduce speed of game
```